# How to get the hex part of unicode in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I have the following list :

```
text = ['\ued07', '\ueedb', '\ueedb', '\uecd0', '\uebf0', '\uf4ee', '\uebf0', '\uf013', '\uecd0', '\uec83', '\ue29d', '\ueedb', '\uecd0', '\uecd0', '\uec83', '\ued07', '\ueedb', '\uecd0', '\uec83', '\uec83', '\uea41', '\uea41', '\uebf0', '\uebf0', '\uecd0', '\ued07', '\uecd0', '\ued07', '\ueedb', '\uec83', '\uebf0', '\uecd0', '\uecd0', '\ued07', '\ue29d', '\ue29d', '\uecd0', '\uecd0', '\ue29d', '\uf4ee', '\uecd0', '\uf013', '\uec83', '\uecd0', '\uea41', '\uebf0', '\uecd0', '\uecd0', '\uecd0']
```

I would like to get the following:

```
result = ['unied07', 'uniedb', 'unieedb', ..., 'uniecd0']
```

How to do it in python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ord(chr)` to get the character value. Then, format it hexadecimally and append `"uni"`.

To convert it back, slice the hex string and use `int('Hex number', 16)`. Then get the character with `chr()`.

Comment: Thank you,CoderCharmander. 

The solution  is : `'result = ['uni' + hex(ord(i))[2:] for i in text]'`.

Comment: How about from `'&#xe1a4;'` to `\ue1a4`?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
unicode_list = ['\ued07', '\ueedb', '\ueedb', '\uecd0', '\uebf0', '\uf4ee', '\uebf0', '\uf013', '\uecd0', '\uec83', '\ue29d', '\ueedb', '\uecd0', '\uecd0', '\uec83', '\ued07', '\ueedb', '\uecd0', '\uec83', '\uec83', '\uea41', '\uea41', '\uebf0', '\uebf0', '\uecd0', '\ued07', '\uecd0', '\ued07', '\ueedb', '\uec83', '\uebf0', '\uecd0', '\uecd0', '\ued07', '\ue29d', '\ue29d', '\uecd0', '\uecd0', '\ue29d', '\uf4ee', '\uecd0', '\uf013', '\uec83', '\uecd0', '\uea41', '\uebf0', '\uecd0', '\uecd0', '\uecd0']

converted_list = []
for unicode in unicode_list:
    converted_list.append(hex(ord(unicode)).replace('0x','uni'))

print(converted_list)
```